One picture disappeared out of a batch taken
On vacation, we took a lot of portrait  photos in a short period of time. We looked at the last picture taken outside, and it came out perfect.  We then went inside to take some more.  After taking some more, when reviewing various photos, I noticed one photo (not the "perfect" one) had the work "Processing" message at the bottom.
I didn't think too much about that, until that evening when reviewing all the photos, and the perfect photo didn't show up.  Nor was it synced to Google Photos. The Google Photos app said "2 files remaining to back up" (or similar).  Checking the next day, all files processed; no "perfect" photo on phone, nor on Google Photos.
I checked my "Trash" folder in Google, the Files app on the phone, and plugged my phone into my computer via USB, and browsed the internal storage of my phone via Windows Explorer.  No luck.  I checked the "Locked" folder on my phone to see if I somehow had it switched to store in the "Locked" folder and it was not there.
Any other possible places to explore?  Was this a rare bug I hit?
Phone:  Google Pixel 8 Pro, Android 14.

I'm supposing the photos were labelled by numeric sequence, and now there's a gap? What clear evidence was the missing one , apart from human recall?

The Pixel camera apps use a date/timestamp in the filename, unlike point&shoot cameras. Such at PXL_20240614_214231763.jpg  Good question though.  I'm 99% sure I did see the mystery picture right after I took it.

AFAIR, taking a batch of photos too quickly might get the disk I/O bottlenecked and corrupted a few (e.g. blank photo), but they should still be listed in the gallery/Google Photos app. As for Google Camera, based on my experience, the processing time might increase significantly if there are too many photos being queued, thus the photo you saw might not have been processed, and after post-processing, the photo looks different. However, it's a wild guess since it's kind of difficult to diagnose the issue due to the post-processing.
